# Good javascript reference

Tags: javascript

What is a good javascript (book or site) that is not just focused on syntax but does a good job explaining how javascript works behind the scenes? Thanks!

Comment: Thread from a while back about JS books: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884/good-javascript-books#74927

Comment: So what do you want? A reference, as stated in your title? Or some book to really learn javascript, as stated in your text?

Comment: I was using the terms interchangeably .. as in a book is also a reference. I am going to check out the Rhino and Crockford books. As I requested, I mainly want something to provide more behind the scenes insight as opposed to a compendium of syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want a book that starts with explaining JavaScript syntax, then:

- Watch the **video lectures of Douglas Crockford** in [YUI Theater](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/):

  - [The JavaScript Programming Language](http://video.yahoo.com/video/play?vid=111593),
  - [Advanced JavaScript](http://video.yahoo.com/video/play?vid=111585),
  - [An Inconvenient API: The Theory of the DOM](http://video.yahoo.com/video/play?vid=111582).
- Read **[Pro JavaScript Techniques](http://jspro.org/)** by John Resig (the author of jQuery library).

  - This book already assumes, that you are pretty familiar with JavaScript syntax and goes in-depth to the really hard and important issues you face in your life with JavaScript.  It teaches you what goes on under the hood of a JavaScript library like jQuery and how you would go to implement your own.

Comment: All links are effectively "dead"

Answer (score 9):

The [JavaScript resources at the Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) are pretty nice. They have a [guide to JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide) as well as a a [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference).

The guide isn't really that great, but the reference is awesome. If I'm looking for something, I just use google with 'mdc' (or 'mdc javascript' in ambiguous cases) + keyword as search terms.

---

It might also be a good idea to read the 3 1/2 page long sections 4.2 and 4.3 of ECMA-262. Also, consider reading chapter 10.

Comment: MDC really works good as a reference, have been using it for quite some time already. Can't imagine anything offline as a reference.

Answer (score 7):

[The rhino book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101992/?CMP=AFC-ak_book&ATT=JavaScript%3A+The+Definitive+Guide) is an excellent book to have on your desk.

Comment: This is THE book. But be sure to get the most recent version (for what I hope are obvious reasons - it's a shape-shifting topic.)

Answer (score 1):

[Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) is a pretty great resource, and it also includes an in-browser environment to test out javascript.

Answer (score 1):

In order of precedence,

1. Flanagan's Definitive Guide ("The Rhino Book", which I upvoted above), followed by
2. anything written or googled for by Douglas Crockford.
3. W3 stuff is great for their try-it-yourself sandboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Others have made some great suggestions ([The Rhino Books](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101992/?CMP=AFC-ak_book&ATT=JavaScript%3A+The+Definitive+Guide), [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript), and references such as [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/default.asp)). Once you get a good grasp on the language, I **highly** recommend [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748/)  by [Douglas Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I've always found the [w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) site excellent for not just for javascript but css and much else web related too.  Has a nice combination of quick syntax reference with example code and tutorials for more depth when required.

Comment: This received a mark down!  Havn't the faintest idea why

Comment: Because it's the wosrt place to learn the web technologies.
http://w3fools.com/

Comment: I have seen A LOT worse than w3schools... I think w3schools is pretty decent for beginners, despite what the criticism at w3fools may say

Comment: hmmm, yes the criticism at w3fools has a fair bit of validity.  However as a quick resource for functions and syntax I'd still say that w3schools is fine.  Maybe the educational aspects could do with improving, but I don't think I've ever looked at it for that.

Answer (score 0):

Eras ago, I used [WebMonkey](http://www.webmonkey.com/tutorial/JavaScript_Tutorial_-_Lesson_1) to edumacate me some.  Nowadays I usually just Google around for specifics - most of it is just finding remembering syntax I find anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

crockford does a good job of explaining JS. check out the articles on his website and his new book:

- http://www.crockford.com/javascript/
- [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)