# What are some of the best reference sites for HTML and JavaScript programming

Tags: javascript, html, reference

Best reference sites for HTML and JavaScript programming:

- [W3C WebEd Wiki](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Main_Page) (this site has a self-teaching curriculum as well as reference material): [HTML](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements), [CSS](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS/Properties)
- W3C Specifications: [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/), [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) (working draft), [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/), [DOM Tech Reports: levels 1-3](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR)
- ECMAScript: [ECMAScript 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (PDF), [ECMAScript 3rd Ed.](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf), [Annotated ES 5.1](http://es5.github.com/),  [HTML ES 3](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/)
- SitePoint: [DOM JavaScript](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/domcore), [HTML](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html), [CSS](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css) -- [Search](http://tools.sitepoint.com/codeburner/)
- Mozilla Dev Center: [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM), [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JavaScript), [JS Lang](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide), [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/AJAX), [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML), [XHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XHTML), [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SVG), [Standards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Web_Standards)
- MSDN: [HTML Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533029.aspx), [IE HTML Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772960.aspx), [CSS Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533029.aspx), [IE CSS Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531209.aspx), [JavaScript Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1et7k7c.aspx), [DOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms764730.aspx)
- Quirksmode: [DOM Javascript](http://quirksmode.org/js/contents.html), [CSS](http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html), [Compatibility](http://quirksmode.org/compatibility.html)
- ZVON: [HTML, XML, CSS](http://www.zvon.org/index.php?nav_id=references&mime=html)
- DevGuru - [JavaScript](http://devguru.com/technologies/javascript/home.asp), [HTML](http://devguru.com/technologies/html/home.asp), [CSS](http://devguru.com/technologies/css2/home.asp), [XML, Server-side](http://devguru.com/technologies/technologies.asp)
- Aptana - [DOM0](http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/HTMLDOM0.index-frame.html), [DOM1+2](http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/HTMLDOM2.index-frame.html), [JavaScript Lang](http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/JSKeywords.index.html), [Core](http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/JSCore.index-frame.html), [HTML](http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/HTML.index.html), [CSS](http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/CSS.index.html)
- GotAPI - [DOM JavaScript](http://www.gotapi.com/jsdomw3s), [HTML](http://www.gotapi.com/html), [CSS, Server-side, Multimedia, XML](http://www.gotapi.com/)
- SELFHTML French: [DOM JavaScript](http://fr.selfhtml.org/javascript/index.htm), [HTML](http://fr.selfhtml.org/html/index.htm), [DHTML](http://fr.selfhtml.org/dhtml/index.htm), [CSS](http://fr.selfhtml.org/css/index.htm), [XML](http://fr.selfhtml.org/xml/index.htm), [Server-side](http://fr.selfhtml.org/)
- SELFHTML German: [DOM JavaScript](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/index.htm), [HTML](http://de.selfhtml.org/html/index.htm), [DHTML](http://de.selfhtml.org/dhtml/index.htm), [CSS](http://de.selfhtml.org/css/index.htm), [XML](http://de.selfhtml.org/xml/index.htm), [Server-side](http://de.selfhtml.org/)
- Blooberry - [HTML](http://blooberry.com/indexdot/html/index.html), [CSS](http://blooberry.com/indexdot/css/index.html)
- HTMLDog - [HTML](http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/), [CSS](http://htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/)
- W3schools: [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_reference.asp), [JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp), [HTML, CSS, XML, Multimedia, Server-side](http://www.w3schools.com/sitemap/sitemap_references.asp)<sup>*</sup>

<sup>*</sup>There is some controversy over the quality and accuracy of the information in the tutorials offered by W3Schools. Not as many, however, take issue with the reference section.

---

Related questions, mostly the source of the above links:

- [What is the best online javascript/css/html/xhtml/dom reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63918/what-is-the-best-online-javascript-css-html-xhtml-dom-reference)
- [Best resources to learn JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript)
- [Good javascript reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458453/good-javascript-reference/458474)

Comment: Why close? Won't such a listing be useful? I'm sure many people could use the info.

Comment: SO is also a wiki, so if you know any useful ref sites, share them. At least don't stop others from sharing.

Comment: This has been asked. Many times.

Comment: Though it has been asked before, its never been compiled into such a list.

Comment: @Mat, this is the first question that appears when I look for terms: [javascript][reference] on SO, it is also foruth in google for the same terms. The problem is that many links here are dead: e.g. Devguru,Aptana. Perhaps the question should be reopened or asked again? I really feel there is a need for a quality list of frequently updated reference materials about js.

Comment: @Pawelmhm: the question is not locked or closed, so I'm not sure what you're asking for. And this type of question doesn't fit Stack Overflow well at all, precisely because the answers rot. If you re-ask it, it will most likely be closed in a very short time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best online javascript/css/html/xhtml/dom reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63918/what-is-the-best-online-javascript-css-html-xhtml-dom-reference)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I find the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide) very helpful.

Steve

Comment: Although its really slow (server speed?) and sparsely filled. SitePoint is much better and gives you browser compatibility per article.

Comment: For the DOM, I agree that SitePoint is more useful. But the MDC is invaluable for info on the JavaScript natives (such as "Array") and their methods (such as Array's "indexOf"). As of writing, the SitePoint reference doesn't seem to have any information on this.

Answer (score 4):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/) has a lot of reference materials for [web development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa155073(en-us).aspx). It contains only IE-specific information which can be either an advantage or a disadvantage depending on what you are looking for. Here are direct links to the [HTML/CSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa155133(en-us).aspx) (includes DOM), [JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hbxc2t98(en-us,VS.85).aspx) (Microsoft flavor of ECMAScript aka JavaScript) and [VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/t0aew7h6(en-us,VS.85).aspx). The documentation is very well written, and is a great source for answers to DOM/JavaScript questions, since they tend to be mostly the same across browsers.

Also, as references go, let's not forget the official specifications for [HTML](http://www.w3.org/html/), [CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/), and the myriad of other standards specified by [W3C](http://www.w3.org/).

Answer (score 3):

[Dev Opera](http://dev.opera.com/) is a great resource, especially the [Web Standards Curriculum](http://dev.opera.com/articles/wsc/). Another one is [HTML dog](http://htmldog.com/).

Answer (score 2):

The [Unofficial online ECMAScript-262 3rd ed. specification](https://bclary.com/log/2004/11/07/) and [Annotated ECMAScript 5.1](http://es5.github.com/) are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I always check [www.zvon.org](http://www.zvon.org), especially the [references](http://www.zvon.org/index.php?nav_id=references&mime=html) section.

Comment: You could edit the main question itself. Add your sites in the same format, with one link per subject on the site, so people can easily understand whats available on the site.

Answer (score 1):

[HTML Code Tutorial](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/) is a decent site, and its [Quick List](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/quicklist.html) page helps me sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

A really helpfull tool for Firefox (with Firebug installed)
http://tools.sitepoint.com/codeburner/

For rapidly find documentation on sitepoint reference.

Answer (score 1):

> Best resources to learn JavaScript

I have been catching up on modern Javascript techniques, and learning some handy tricks, by running, reading and editing GreaseMonkey scripts from userscripts.org.

Answer (score 1):

While not directly a reference site, LearningLine rolls many of these sites into their lessons as well as sites like http://caniuse.com/.

https://learninglineapp.com/schedule

Here are some of the courses that are good starting points:

- [Essential jQuery](https://learninglineapp.com/courses/14/client-side-programming-with-knockoutjs)
- [HMTL5 in-depth](https://learninglineapp.com/courses/8/hmtl5-in-depth)
- [Getting started with JavaScript](https://learninglineapp.com/courses/32/getting-started-with-javascript)
- [Client-side programming with KnockoutJS](https://learninglineapp.com/courses/14/client-side-programming-with-knockoutjs)

Cheers,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

I've found [AeroTwist](https://aerotwist.com/blog/%20%22AeroTwist) very useful for learning rendering performance.