# jQuery function not happening on hover mouseleave

Tags: jquery, mouseleave, jquery-hover

I'm trying to make a small animation for a website I'm working on but the way I have built it, when I speed my mouse over the container div, the animation still happens. How do I get this to recognize that the mouse isn't actually hovering?

The HTML code is:

```
<div id="badge">
    <div id="slogan">
        <p>We sell for less!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="icon"></div>
    <div id="name"></div>
    <div id="TMhold">
        <div id="TM"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the jQuery I'm using:

```
$("#badge").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop(true,true).animate({width: "250px"}, 760, "easeOutQuart");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#TM").stop(true,true).animate({top: "0"}, 500, "easeOutQuart");
        }, 500 );
        setTimeout(function(pee) {
            $('#badge p').stop(true,true).animate({opacity: .99}, 760, "easeOutQuart");
        }, 800 );
    },
    function() {
        clearTimeout(pee);
        $('#badge p').stop(true,true).animate({opacity: 0}, 120, "easeOutQuart");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#badge').stop(true,true).animate({width: "90px"}, 900, "easeOutQuart");
            $("#TM").stop(true,true).animate({ top: "-13px"}, 500, "easeOutQuart");
        }, 300 );   
    }
);
```

I've read about the clearTimeout function but I'm not sure if that applies to this as my solution.

Thanks so much for any help or clarification!

Comment: I suggest you practice proper spacing and indentation of your code to aid in readability and troubleshooting.  I edited your post to show what I'm talking about.

Comment: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a little time just rearranging the layout of the JavaScript to help see what was really happening, and I think I see what you might be missing.  The `setTimeout` method returns a value to represent the timer that is being set.  If you don't capture this value, you won't be able to cancel the timer.

Instead of calling `setTimeout( function(pee)...`, change it to capture the return value, and then use that value in the `clearTimeout` call.

```
var hoverTimerId;

$("#badge").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).stop(true,true).animate({width: "250px"}, 760, "easeOutQuart");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#TM").stop(true,true).animate({top: "0"}, 500, "easeOutQuart");
        }, 500);
        hoverTimerId = setTimeout(function() {
           $('#badge p').stop(true,true).animate({ opacity: .99}, 760, "easeOutQuart");
        }, 800);
    },
    function(){
        clearTimeout(hoverTimerId);
        $('#badge p').stop(true,true).animate({opacity: 0}, 120, "easeOutQuart");

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#badge').stop(true,true).animate({ width: "90px"}, 900, "easeOutQuart");
            $("#TM").stop(true,true).animate({top: "-13px"}, 500, "easeOutQuart");
        }, 300);
    }
);
```

NOTE: The timer Id needs to be available in both the `handlerIn` and `handlerOut` callbacks, so I made it a global variable outside the `hover` method call.  You could possibly define that inside the `hover` call and have it still work.  I have not tested it either way.

Comment: awesome! This worked perfectly. The only thing is now, the "TM" div is staying after roll out. I tried creating another var and a clearTimeout for that as well but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @brock2621 - not sure on that one. In the code update I provided, the TM animation is in a new timeout function. It looks like it should animate after just a short delay.

Comment: I'm curious to know why this has been downvoted.  Did I miss something or not answer the question?

Comment: w3schools is not a respected resource around here.  Sometimes answers which reference it are down-voted.

Comment: @Sparky672 - well, that's good to know.  I didn't know I was supposed to avoid it as a resource.  It's been pretty good with quick JavaScript syntax references.  Can you recommend a better resource that has comprehensive syntax reference?

Comment: @Sparky672 - I answered my own question with a quick search: [Best Reference Sites](http://stackoverflow.com/q/823718/475820).  I've only relied on the reference section of w3schools, not the tutorials, which I agree are not the greatest.